# Python: Is there a way to execute an or statement before !=

Tags: python, python-3.x, operand

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
while check == False:
    op = input('Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide?')
    if op != ((('add' or 'subtract') or 'multiply') or 'divide'):
        print('Please enter a valid operation')
    else:
        check = True
```

However, only 'add' is seen as a valid input. Is there a way to execute this code without using nested if statements so that all 4 options are valid?

Comment: Why not use a set and simply test if the value of *op* exists in that set. It'll avoid nested *if* statements and all this crazy boolean logic.

Comment: You need to check the syntax of a language. The `or` binary operator does not work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the `not in` operator:

```
if op not in ['add', 'substract', 'multiply', 'divide']:
    print('Please enter a valid operation')
```

`in` checks for an item in a *container*, `not in` just does the opposite.

---

Or additionally, as @Chris_Rands suggests, replace the list by a set for efficiency:

```
if op not in {'add', 'substract', 'multiply', 'divide'}:
    print('Please enter a valid operation')
```

Comment: better to use `in {}` than `in []`. Sets are faster than lists for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make each comparison individually, so `op != 'add' and op != 'subtract'...`.

Answer (score 0):

`or` operator *is* executed before `!=`. What you doing wrong is that you are working with wrong operands:

```
'add' or 'substract'
>>> 'add'
```

This means that in the end it will be:

```
if 'op' != 'add':
```

That is exactly what you get. What you need to do is to compare op to each operation you allow:

```
if (op != 'add') and (op != 'substract'):
```

or with python-fu

```
validOperations = ['add, 'substract']
if op not in validOperations:
```

Comment: `if (op != 'add') or (op != 'substract'):` --> wrong; it should be the *and* operator not *or*.

Comment: @0x23212f true, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` and a list.

```
while check == False:
    op = input('Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide?')
    if op not in ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide']:
        print('Please enter a valid operation')
    else:
        check = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen on an answer similar to your code, this works:

```
check = False
while check == False:
  op = raw_input('add/subtract/multiply/divide ? : ')
  if op != 'add' and op != 'subtract' and op != 'multiply' and op != 'divide':
    print 'What? Choose wisely.'
  else:
    print 'Well chosen.'
    check = True
```